Is this function well-defined? $f(x) = \sin x - \sin( \sin x)+ \sin (\sin( \sin x)) - \cdots$
Is this function
$$f(x) = \sin x -  \sin( \sin x)+ \sin (\sin( \sin x)) - \sin(\sin(\sin(\sin x)))+ \cdots$$
well defined for $x \in \mathbb R$?
Is it differentiable?
I am asking this question just out of curiosity.

To have it well defined you need the sum to converge.  Do you have any thoughts?

Not sure about differentiability, but the function is well-defined. Since $|\sin x| \le |x|$ for all $x$, the sequence $|\sin^n(x)|$, where powers denote compositional powers, is monotone decreasing. And, since $|\sin x| < |x|$ for $x \neq 0$ (and $0$ is the only root in the range of $\sin$), this sequence will either be eventually $0$ or strictly monotone decreasing. Moreover, $\sin^n(x)$ will have the same sign for $n \ge 2$. So, by the alternating series test, the series does indeed converge (likely conditionally).

Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

So asking a math question "just out of curiosity" in context of "calculus"  does not match "standard" of mathstack?

@Basics It's to do with a lack of displayed attempts on your part. It's a rule designed to discourage people from asking for pre-packaged answers to questions from homework assignments, and as such, makes little sense to apply here. But, people can get in trouble for bending the rules these days, so closed your question remains.

I still don't understand.
It's not a question from homework assignments or not related to any projects.
I asked the question "just out of curiosity" and had no other intention or context.
If people are not interested in the question, they will simply ignore it or even downvote it. But being voted to close is not what I expect.
So Is it subject to voting-to-close to ask a question just out of curiosity without more context here in mathstack?

@Basics While the intention behind the rule is to do with homework questions, the rule itself is not subject to whether or not the question is homework. Some would argue that it should be applied to all questions, yours included. Others would argue that it makes little sense to apply the rule to your question. Honestly, I personally believe a bit of both, and not without serious cognitive dissonance, though the latter slightly more than the former. As such, I didn't vote your question to close, and have voted to re-open it.

Let $\mathcal {g}_{1} \left( x \right) = \sin \left( x \right)$ and $\mathcal {g}_{n + 1} \left( x \right) = \sin \left( \mathcal {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \right)$. Define
$$\mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} {\left( - 1 \right)}^{k - 1} \mathcal {g}_{k} \left( x \right).$$
If $\mathcal {g}_{1} \left( x \right) > 0$, then, since $\mathcal {g}_{1} \left( x \right) \le 1$, $0 < \mathcal {g}_{2} \left( x \right) \le \sin \left( 1 \right)$ where $1 < \pi / 2$, so $\sin \left( 1 \right) < 1$. By induction, we find that $0 < \mathcal {g}_{n} \left( x \right) < 1$ for all $n \ge 2$. Since $\sin \left( x \right) < x$ for all $x \neq 0$, we have $\mathcal {g}_{n + 1} \left( x \right) < \mathcal {g}_{n} \left( x \right)$. The fact

that the  sequence ${\left \{ \mathcal {g}_{n} \left( x \right) \right \}}_{n \ge 1}$ is bounded below, and
that it is decreasing

guarantees existence of the limit ${G}_{x} = \mathcal {g}_{\infty} \left( x \right)$, which is one such that ${G}_{x} = \sin \left( {G}_{x} \right)$; this is to say, ${G}_{x} = 0$. By the alternating series test, we find ${\left \{ \mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right) \right \}}_{n \ge 1}$ to be convergent.
If $\mathcal {g}_{1} \left( x \right) = 0$, then $\mathcal {g}_{n} \left( x \right) = 0$ and $\mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right) = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$.
If $\mathcal {g}_{1} \left( x \right) < 0$, ustilising the oddity of $\mathcal {g}_{n} \left( x \right)$ and $\mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right)$, show that ${\left \{ \mathcal {f}_{n} \left( x \right) \right \}}_{n \ge 1}$ converges.

In conclusion, the limit ${F}_{x} = \mathcal {f}_{\infty} \left( x \right)$ exists for all $x \in \mathbb {R}$. Displayed above are ${\left \{ \mathcal {g}_{{2}^{n}} \left( x \right) \right \}}_{n = 0}^{7}$ for $0 \le x \le \ \pi / 2$. I include the graph for the record.

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

@MartinR, thanks for the links. It seems I've been overly lenient. I shall adopt a stricter standard.
